# Download image on my server using php

Tags: javascript, php, image, button

I have a div class for an image search button:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        var link = "https://source.unsplash.com/all/?";
        var articleTitle = "<?php echo "'" . $article->title . "'"; ?>";
        function myFunction() {
            var d = new Date();
            var c = link + articleTitle + "[" + d.getTime()+"]";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<img src=" + c + " height='100' width='100'/>" ;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Each click on this button gives me a new image by my keyword ($article->title) with a unique http url.

And I want to do one more button, which will save the image founded by first button on my server. I want to use something like this:

```
<?php 
     $image = file_get_contents("c");
     file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\test\htdocs\image\image.jpg', $image);
?>
```

Where "c" is my link from first button.

So the question is: What should I change here: `file_get_contents("c");` as I want place my url from first button into  `file_get_contents` , because `file_get_contents("c");` this method didnt work.

Comment: You can't create PHP-code from javascript... PHP is executed on the server, then sent to the client where any javascript will be executed.

Comment: Hi, @MagnusEriksson it is possible to write php code into js!

Comment: Sure it is.. but it won't execute. The browser (where the JS is executed) don't have a PHP-parser.

Comment: it will also execute but definitely in the server not in the browser.

Comment: How do you execute interactive JS on the server using DOM objects (like button clicks)!?

Comment: Hey, when you will write the php into the js then file extension is .php and the server will do the rest of things.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying!. He is dynamically building PHP-code within a `<script>`-tag (using results from the JS) on the web page. That doesn't work!

Comment: Guys maybe somebody want to help me solve this problem?))))

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to save an image which is generated using javascript to your server, using php? As php code is only executed on page load, you have to use a form submit and save the image in the target php file (which of course can be the same file) or you have to use an AJAX request to a second php file, which saves the image.

A solution without AJAX could look something like that:

```
<form name="save_img_form" action="[target file or same file]" method="[get/post]"
onsubmit="document.save_img_form.img_src = c; return true;">
 <input type="hidden" name="img_src" value="" />
 <input type="submit" value="save image" />
</form>
```

In order for this to work, you have to define the variable c globally. Change the line `var c = link ...` to `c = link ...`, so the variable becomes global (compare here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

On the target page (or same page) you use something like this to retrieve the image source:

```
<?php 
$img_src = $_GET["img_src"];  //or use $_POST, if you have used this method.
?>
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the image source.

Comment: If you want to use AJAX, see for example this page: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml